# Missing required parameter for ROUTE in laravel 8

Tags: parameters, routes, laravel-8

I have problem on my route :

Missing required parameter for [Route: panitia.update] [URI: admin/panitia/{panitium}] [Missing parameter: panitium]. (View: C:\Users\MbenDaris\Documents\Project\betta\resources\views\admin\panitia\edit.blade.php)

*This my controller:*

```
public function edit(Panitia $panitias)
{
    return view('admin.panitia.edit', compact('panitias'));
}
```

*this my code edit.blade.php:*

```
<form action="{{ route('panitia.update', $panitias->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

*this my route:*

```
Route::resource('admin/panitia', PanitiaController::class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

***web.php***

```
Route::resource('admin/panitia', PanitiaController::class);
```

if your path like as above , then your controller function will as under:

***PanitiaController.php***

```
public function edit($pantia_id)
{
     $panitias = Panitia::find($pantia_id);
     return view('admin.panitia.edit', compact('panitias'));
}
```

and form code is as given:

**edit.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('panitia.update', $panitias->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thank for the answer,  i will try this code

Answer (score 2):

['route' => ['panitia.update',$panitias->id]]

Check your route also, is it a resource route ?

Comment: thanks for answer, this problem has been solved but i have new problem. if i put the button update, showing not found on page

Comment: <form action="['route' => ['panitia.update',$panitias->id]]" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')

Comment: Not found on the page or after clicking that button ?